# Django social_auth for facebook no longer working

Tags: django, facebook, heroku, django-socialauth

I had social_auth set up with facebook log-in for a Django app. However, recently it stopped working (even though I made no changes to the code as far as I recall). Before it worked fine, but now when I try to log in I get the following error from the Django debug screen that results:
[image]

[image]

Through some further debugging I realized that the "response" variable in the facebook.py file when running the auth_complete function was non-empty, but then the parsed_response variable does not parse the response correctly and thus ends up empty. Thus in the facebook.py file of the social authentication backend, I changed the following line of code:

```
   parsed_response = cgi.parse_qs(response)

    access_token = parsed_response['access_token'][0]
    if 'expires' in parsed_response:
        expires = parsed_response['expires'][0]
```

To the following:

```
    import ast
    parsed_response = ast.literal_eval(response)

    access_token = parsed_response['access_token']
    if 'expires' in parsed_response:
        expires = parsed_response['expires']
```

And it works!

However, this seems like a hack to me. After scouring the web for people experiencing a similar problem with the social_auth login, I couldn't find any relevant posts. Similarly, it seems odd that it just stopped working all of a sudden as it was working this entire time. Thus, I feel like although this is a working solution, it is not *the* solution, as when I try to upload to Heroku or something that downloads and installs its own dependencies I will not be able to implement such a hack unless I make custom backend pipelines.

Maybe there is something obvious I am missing.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Copy and paste the traceback - it's more readable and makes it searchable for future visitors.

Comment: _“Similarly, it seems odd that it just stopped working all of a sudden as it was working this entire time.”_ – no, what’s odd is that so many people can’t be bothered to follow the announcements Facebook makes about such API changes way upfront.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you have hit [this issue](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/1094). It appears to have been fixed in python-social-auth.

You have tagged your question [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth), but it was deprecated in favour of `python-social-auth`. The [current recommendation](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html) appears to be to install `social-auth-core` and the `social-app-django` app.